# Show that the quotient space $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$ has trivial topology.

Tags: general-topology

Show that the quotient space $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$ has trivial (coarsest) topology.

Attempt:
Let $\mathfrak{A}$ be any nonempty open set in $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Q}$. 
the union $A:=\bigcup\mathfrak{A}$ is nonempty open set of $\mathbb{R}$. I observe that $\mathfrak{A}$ must contain the coset $\mathbb{Q}$. Because $A$ contains some interval of $\mathbb{R}$ hence contain some rational number. But the only coset having a rational number is $\mathbb{Q}$ itself, hence $\mathbb{Q}$ is contained in $A$. So $\mathbb{Q}\in \mathfrak{A}$. I want to show that $A=\mathbb{R}$ but how? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can milk more out of the observation "$A$ contains an interval". More precisely you can show that this implies that $A$ contains numbers from **every** coset of $\Bbb{Q}$ in $\Bbb{R}$. Therefore $\mathfrak{A}$ was all of $\Bbb{R}/\Bbb{Q}$.